# TweepError: Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/update.json?status= (Caused by SSL error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

every tutorial i've looked at all look the same and like my code so i dont understand why i keep getting an error, i am a beginner and im just trying to make tweepy update my twitter status through python.

```
import tweepy  # import libraries

# setting up the commands
CONSUMER_KEY = '...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '...'
ACCESS_KEY = '...'
ACCESS_SECRET = '...'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
# send a tweet

api.update_status("lol")
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You have the necessary keys etc.?

Comment: yea i even regenerated new ones to make sure the keys were good